# The relation between the limit cardinal $\alpha$ and a sequence of cardinal numbers strictly less than $\alpha$

Tags: set-theory

For a limit cardinal $\alpha$ can we find a sequence of sets $(X_n)$ with $card X_1< card X_2<...< card X$and $card X= card X_1+ card X_2+...?$

Comment: What do the $\dots$ mean here? (Yes, I get it, an infinite sequence, but how long exactly?)

Answer (score 2):

Your question suggests you are looking for a countable sequence; then the answer is: NO.
$\aleph_{\omega_1}$ is a limit cardinal, but not the sum of countably many smaller cardinals. 
You may want to study the notion [`cofinality of a cardinal number'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofinality#Cofinality_of_ordinals_and_other_well-ordered_sets).